# Beginner Javascript Project for Cash Register

Tags: javascript, methods

I am just beginning the exciting journey towards learning Javascript, and in one of my lessons I am being asked to build a voidLastTransaction method to add to my virtual cash register. I have written out the code, which allows the user to void the amount from the last transaction. However, I would like to know how to do it to void the last two transactions, rather than one. I suppose calling the function after each transaction I want voided is one way of doing it; but I am wondering if there is a more dynamic way of resetting the property that stores the amount of the last transaction so that it changes to the value of the previous transaction on the list, which would become the next "last transaction" once the last transaction has been deducted. Below is my current code. Thanks in advance!

```
var cashRegister = {
total: 0,
lastTransactionAmount: 0,
add: function(itemCost) {
   this.total += itemCost;
   this.lastTransactionAmount = itemCost;
},
scan: function(item, quantity) {
switch (item) {
  case "eggs": this.add(0.98 * quantity); break;
  case "milk": this.add(1.23 * quantity); break;
  case "magazine": this.add(4.99 * quantity); break;
  case "chocolate": this.add(0.45 * quantity); break;
} 
return true;
}, 

voidLastTransaction: function() {
  this.total -= this.lastTransactionAmount;
  this.lastTransactionAmount = 0;
}
}; 

cashRegister.scan("eggs", 1);
cashRegister.scan("milk", 1);
cashRegister.scan("magazine", 1);
cashRegister.scan("chocolate", 4); 

// I want to void the last 2 transactions
console.log("your bill is" + cashRegister.total);
```

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to do this. I will post an answer, which I find is the mosy understandable for people new to js

Comment: Thank you, I just finished the course but still feel unfamiliar with some things :/ I will continue to study this so thank you for answering! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an array, it's easier to get the last transactions and apply the items to total. The fact that an array is sequential is an ideal candidate to track transcations added. Moreover JavaScript array can easily be used as a stack or a queue.

I've replaced your lastTransactionAmount with transactions:[]

Below is untested, so probably buggy:

```
var cashRegister = {
total: 0,

// use array instead,
// for the problem in question it will function as a stack
transactions:[],

add: function(itemCost) {
   this.total += itemCost;
   this.transactions.push(itemCost); // add each item to array
},

scan: function(item, quantity) {
switch (item) {
  case "eggs": this.add(0.98 * quantity); break;
  case "milk": this.add(1.23 * quantity); break;
  case "magazine": this.add(4.99 * quantity); break;
  case "chocolate": this.add(0.45 * quantity); break;
} 
return true;
},

  voidLastTransaction: function(total) {
    // the immediately following single operation, get's the last element
    // in the array (stack), which coincides with the last recorded transaction
    // and at the same time, it removes the element from the stack!
    // So every time this method is called you have one less transaction.
    var lastTransactionCost = this.transactions.pop();
    this.total -= lastTransactionCost;
  }
}; 

cashRegister.scan("eggs", 1);
cashRegister.scan("milk", 1);
cashRegister.scan("magazine", 1);
cashRegister.scan("chocolate", 4);

console.log("Current outstanding total: " + cashRegister.total);

console.log("About to void the last 3 transactions...");

var numberOfTransactionsToCancel = 3;
while(numberOfTransactionsToCancel--){
    cashRegister.voidLastTransaction();
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm unfamiliar with a few things such as  the .push and .splice methods. Are these defaults? Could you explain further? Thank you!!

Comment: push is an array method, of which there are many. so `var arr=[];` and to add stuff: `arr.push(23,81, 'abc');` splice and pop are other useful methods of Array. They exist as native methods of JS.

Comment: Thanks! The lesson did not cover these, and I know there is a website where I could find  explanations of uses for defaults such as these. Where can I find some references for these many array methods, if you don't mind me asking? Thank  you!!

Comment: you can only learn by trial and error, in fact you learn the most when you're stuck and stumble across stuff that makes you say 'that's something i learned today'.

Comment: :) thank you for answering all my questions and keeping true to the spirit of learning - thank you for sharing some of your knowledge with me :)

Comment: if you're happy, i'm happy ;) jeff way is an EXCELLENT teacher and i don't say that lightly; you will get some valuable insight by watching this: http://code.tutsplus.com/courses/30-days-to-learn-jquery

Comment: And I won't take that lightly either, you sound like a great teacher yourself, so thank you! :) I will mos def check this out!

Comment: Haha ok I won't! Thanks!

Comment: @Nancy, here's where you can find trusted documentation on native array methods, and notes on browser supports for them: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: The methods are listed on the left panel of the page. When click on any, you get a full detail of how it works and other interesting gists. For learning JavaScript and other web technologies freely, MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) is a reliable and an unbiased source you can use.

Comment: @IgweKalu Thank you so much for the guides! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would write it.

1) Create a database object to hold and manage inventory.

```
var inventory = (function() {
    var inventory = {
        items: {},

        exists: function(itemName) {
            return typeof this.items[itemName] !== "undefined";    
        },

        add: function(itemName, info) {
            if(!this.exists(itemName)) {
                this.items[itemName] = info;
            }

            return this;
        },

        get: function(itemName) {
            if(!this.exists(itemName)) {
                throw new Error("item [" + itemName + "] is not in the database.");
            }

            return this.items[itemName];
        }
    };

    return {
        add: inventory.add.bind(inventory),
        get: inventory.get.bind(inventory)
    };
})();
```

2) Load/instantiate inventory.  The `add()` returns `this`, which allows chaining of the `add` methods.

```
inventory.add("eggs", {price: 0.98})
         .add("milk", {price: 1.23})
         .add("magazine", {price: 4.99})
         .add("chocolate", {price: 0.45});
```

3) Create `Transction` function/object that will be used as a constructor and will store details of each transaction.

```
function Transaction(itemName, quantity) {
    this.itemName = itemName;
    this.price = inventory.get(itemName).price;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.total = this.price * this.quantity;
}
```

4) Create `Order` function/object that will be created to hold and manage an order per each customer.

```
function Order() {
    this.transactions = [];
}
```

5) Add functions to `Order` prototype that will be used to manage an order.

```
Order.prototype.scan = function(itemName, quantity) {
    this.transactions.push(new Transaction(itemName, quantity));
};

Order.prototype.voidLast = function(num) {
    num || (num = 1);
    var start = this.transactions.length - num;
    this.transactions.splice(start, num);
};

Order.prototype.total = function() {
    return this.transactions.reduce(function(total, transaction) {
        return total + transaction.total;    
    }, 0);
};
```

And, 6) Put it all to work.

```
var myOrder = new Order();
myOrder.scan("eggs", 2);
myOrder.scan("milk", 3);
myOrder.scan("eggs", 1);

myOrder.voidLast(2);

console.log(myOrder.total().toFixed(2));
```

or, if in the browser do the following:

```
var byId = document.getElementById.bind(document);
byId("total").innerHTML = "$" + myOrder.total().toFixed(2);
```

And 7) Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L9dqkn1n/.

Comment: Wow , thanks first of all for answering. My mind is blown, I must study more! Thank you!

Comment: I have a question: did you add to the Order prototype because you are anticipating various orders and want to be able to use those functions for all orders? Thanks!

Comment: Yeap, that's the idea.  Conversely, the inventory is wrapped in a closure and is accessible only through the returned methods, because it is unlikely that more than one inventory object is necessary.

Comment: So the inventory is private then? I understand about not needing more than one inventory but since this is a "cash register", wouldn't it be okay to have public access to the inventory for our "cashiers"? Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: DRD's inventory object is a lovely example of encapsulation. The only exposure of that object is `add` and `get`, you don't need to worry about what goes on inside. The return object is like an api or interface. Because it's a closure, all variables inside keep their values, so it's a very powerful pattern.

Comment: But what's with all the secrecy? "Encapsulation" or "closure" - I have a vague idea of those concepts...and wow, I'm amazed at how you can simulate an api! :) inspired and selfdoubting now! Lol...

Comment: Ah, I think I see your point about the closure making sure all the variables inside are not changed and  so keep their values. I guess I was considering the context of this (cash register) which can also require for values to change at some point, seeing as prices change. That, and I hate secrets haha - but it seems useful for the entire closure thing to be here . Thanks DRD and Data :)

Comment: Sure thing.  Keep hammering on.  A good JavaScript book is "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide" by David Flanagan.  I am working on my own JS text, but it won't be out for about 2 months, so stay tuned for that. :) Cheers.

Comment: @DRD - what's the gist of your upcoming book/text?

Comment: The book will start "JavaScript by Application" series and will focus on foundational and fundamental JS by writing seven versions of browser-based game of Tic-Tac-Toe, hence the subtitle "Tic-Tac-Toe 7even Ways."  The book is in the same spirit as my "Functional CSS" volumes; it approaches programming purely through practical and immersive cases.

Comment: Wow, that's awesome @DRD! Thanks for your help and I'll make sure to look up your book and the other one too! :]

Answer (score 0):

Try this.This worked for me...

```
var cashRegister = {
    total:0,
    lastTransactionAmount: 0,

    //Dont forget to add your property
    add: function(itemCost) {
        this.lastTransactionAmount = itemCost;
        this.total +=  itemCost;

    },
    scan: function(item,quantity) {
        switch (item) {
        case "eggs": this.add(0.98 * quantity); break;
        case "milk": this.add(1.23 * quantity); break;
        case "magazine": this.add(4.99 * quantity); break;
        case "chocolate": this.add(0.45 * quantity); break;
        }
        return true;
    },
    //Add the voidLastTransaction Method here
    voidLastTransaction: function () {
        this.total -= this.lastTransactionAmount;
    }


};

cashRegister.scan('eggs',1);
cashRegister.scan('milk',1);
cashRegister.scan('magazine',1);
cashRegister.scan('chocolate',4);

//Void the last transaction and then add 3 instead
cashRegister.voidLastTransaction();
cashRegister.scan('chocolate',3);

//Show the total bill
console.log('Your bill is '+cashRegister.total);
`
```